# Adding a ADF permissions to key vault in ARM

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Basically,  I'm trying to add the ability for a data factory to be able to get see secrets from a key vault via the ARM key-vault template so it's applied on a release.

However, the issue comes when I trying to release the project I get an error saying the data factory is not in the same resource group (which was kind of expected), however, I can't see a way of passing in the resource group in order for the function to see the correct resource group where the data factory is located.

```
"accessPolicies": [

          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('DataFactoryName')),'2018-06-01','Full').identity.principalId]",
            "permissions": {
              "secrets": [
                "Get"
              ]
            }
          }
```

Can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the parameter `OtherGroupName` in the `parameters`, the value of  `OtherGroupName` needs to be the resource group name of your datafactory.

```
"OtherGroupName":{
    "type": "String"
}
```

Then use the `accessPolicies` like below:

```
 "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "[reference(ResourceId(parameters('OtherGroupName'), 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('DataFactoryName')),'2018-06-01','Full').identity.principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get"
                            ],
                            "certificates": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

---

**My complete sample**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaults_joykeyvault12_name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "DataFactoryName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "OtherGroupName":{
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vaults_joykeyvault12_name')]",
            "location": "eastus",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "family": "A",
                    "name": "Standard"
                },
                "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "[reference(ResourceId(parameters('OtherGroupName'), 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('DataFactoryName')),'2018-06-01','Full').identity.principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get"
                            ],
                            "certificates": []
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enabledForDeployment": false,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
                "enableSoftDelete": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I test it with powershell `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`, it works fine.

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]